# FontAwesome SVGs do not match their Icon Font, nor the Cheatsheet

Tags: fonts, icons

I am a FontAwesome Pro user.

I've been using the font in my prototype, but I downloaded the folder of assets from the site because my devs want to use SVGs. The pro light weight folder of SVGs are very different from what is seen on the Cheatsheet, or the font itself. Some icons are missing completely. Some are named something else.

Example: Looking for a swimming pool icon.
On the cheatsheet it looks like this:

[image]

Or there's a swimmer on the cheatsheet:

[image]

In the folder of SVGs they only have this:

[image]

They have different names and the icon isn't even the same. What gives? Customer service isn't getting back to me. Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: It may be an issue of version differences per icon set. Has that been confirmed?

Answer (score 0):

I got a response back from FA on Github:

**You download the alpha 2 version of Font Awesome 6, which is in private alpha
The version on the website is the latest stable. If you need icons from the website, please download Font Awesome 5**

Hope that helps anyone else dealing with this!